# Android: External Menu Class

Tags: android, class, external

I'm new to Java and Android development. I'm making simple app only for study purposes. I've learnt how to make menu button functions etc., but it's pretty weird to write this code in every class file:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            try {
                Class activityClass1 = Class.forName("com.epicandroidapp.MenuActivity");
                Intent activityIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass1);
                startActivity(activityIntent1);
                return true;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        case 2:
            return true;
        case 3:
            try {
                Class activityClass2 = Class.forName("com.epicandroidapp.AboutActivity");
                Intent activityIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass2);
                startActivity(activityIntent2);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        case 4:
            try {
                Class activityClass3 = Class.forName("com.epicandroidapp.VersionActivity");
                Intent activityIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass3);
                startActivity(activityIntent3);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I can't find any tutorial or something like this. So is it possible with some external file, which will be like some constructor or something?

Thank's for answer
Maximilian Kulikov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this much smaller code for each case in the switch statement:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.epicandroidapp.MenuActivity.class));
```

or if you import the class:

```
import com.epicandroidapp.MenuActivity;

startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
```

**Edit:** if you mean the entire code, then you need to use XML resources, as discussed in this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

For example, you create an xml file containing a menu (saving it in res/menu/filename.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/item1"
          android:title="@string/item1"/>
</menu>
```

and then in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` you do:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filename, menu);
    return true;
}
```

in your `onOptionsItemSelected` method, you use `getItemId` to get the id of the menu item selected, such as:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Note, all this example code is from the android tutorial about menus.

Comment: Bojan Kogoj: Yeah, that's what i meant.

Comment: The second part of my answer should answer the question for you.

Comment: Is it possible to write the third code in xml? something like:
android:onClick="@android:--command for activity switch--="activity_main""
So i can rewrite the button function for all of the activities?

Comment: If you're targeting Android 3.0 and above, there is an `onClick` attribute which takes a public method in your activity. If you want multiple activities with the same code, you could make a static class with a load of public static methods which do the same thing.